# Chrome: Glyphicon in button in svg misplaced

Tags: google-chrome, svg, glyphicons

In a group project I am involved in, we have a svg with circles and small buttons below them. The buttons should have a plus sign in them.
For this, we use a foreignObject with a bootstrap button and the Plus glyphicon. It works in Firefox, but in Chrome, all the plus signs are at a wrong position.
Here is a small example:[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sg977mvv/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG GLYPHICON TEST</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <g transform="translate(100,100)">
        <circle r="20" style="fill: rgb(141, 211, 199); stroke-width: 1.5px;"></circle>
        <text dy=".35em" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 10px;">Node</text>
        <foreignObject width="24" height="24" x="-12" y="21.276970964404327">
            <body>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    text
                </button>
            </body>
        </foreignObject>
    </g>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

For me, Chrome shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqavk.jpg),
whereas Firefox seems to render it properly.

Is there a workaround for this?
Or another way to include a button in svg, that does not cause this problem in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```css
.glyphicon {
  position: static;
}
```

works in chrome, firefox, opera
so should work in safari, but not tested